# C# Windows Service not able to launch an exe

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

I have a c# Windows Service that is required to call an exe periodically. 
That exe need to interact with desktop. When I installed the service, I clicked
"Allow service to interact with desktop" option.

[image]

Service Starts fine but it is not running the exe as expected.

```
        var myProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\windows\TestApplication\TestApplication.exe"),
            //StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\temp\Projects\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\bin\Debug\TestConsoleApp.exe"),
        };
        myProcess.StartInfo.Domain = "MyDomain";
        myProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "Testuser";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Password = pwd;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Any ideas as to what could be the issue? Is Local System Account does not have access to the System ? How do I find the Local System Account?

Any pointers?

Comment: That option was depreciated in Vista, you should be using the design where your service communicates with an application thats run when a user logs on.  Consider the situation where there are 2 interactive users, given your current design what session/desktop would the application run in?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will have to rethink the design then. My Application (Windows Service) scans  a table in database, gets all document and user webBrowser.Print() to print to PDF. webBrowser.Print() was the part that was failing when I had service in release mode . (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/bbff0a59-b05d-4fe4-81b2-a05c78305345/mshtml-failing-to-work-in-release-mode?forum=ieextensiondevelopment) . Then Chose to convert the webBrowser.Print() to a console app and tried to fire it with my service.